# Is there any way to capture key (key code) event from SoftKeyboard in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyevent

I wanted to capture the **ENTER** and **Backspace** key press event for `EditText` view from the softKeyboard (Not hardware keyboard) in android, like on any `xyz_editText` view someone press the Backspace key from softKeyboard then I want to capture that the `BackSpace` key is pressed.

I tried using `onkeypress()` event but it did not work, I guess it works only for the hardware keyboard events. I need help.